# Making a checkbox field value null using a JS function

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, rerender, onclick

I am trying to set the value of a checkbox(custom field) to null in a VF page using Javascript function.Below are bits and pieces of my code.
This happens when the user clicks the  tag. An Onclick JS function is called which used the DOM to make the checkbox as null.

**Problem :-** the check box value is made as null however on the UI it still shows as checked but the text box shows empty immediately when I click 
Apex Image. The alert message in my JS function shows the Value is 1 for check box. I put that to make sure I get the correct DOM path of the checkbox.

```
<script>
resetInfoDOM(){
    alert('Before resetInfoDOM ' + document.getElementById("{!$Component.thePage:editForm:editFormBlock:someoutputpanel:pagesectionID3:checboxId}").value); // 1
    document.getElementById("{!$Component.thePage:editForm:editFormBlock:someoutputpanel:someoutputpanel:pagesectionID3:checboxId}").value=null;
    alert('After resetInfoDOM ' + document.getElementById("{!$Component.thePage:editForm:editFormBlock:someoutputpanel:pagesectionID3:checboxId}").value); // shows blank
    document.getElementById("thePage:editForm:editFormBlock:someoutputpanel:pagesectionID2:textId").value=null;
}
</script>
```

Part of the VF page:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="pagesectionID1">
    <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.fields.Afield.Label}" />
        <apex:actionRegion>
        <span class="lookupInput">
        <div class="requiredInput">
        <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
        <apex:inputText id="Alookup"  value="{!productCode}" rendered="{!FMP != true}" title="{!$Label.Afield}" label="{!$Label.Afield}" required="true">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="someoutputpanel" action="{!callAFunction}" status="loadStatus"/>
        </apex:inputText>
        <apex:selectList value="{!var}" size="1" rendered="{!FMP == true}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!optionSome}"/>
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="someoutputpanel" action="{!someCode}" status="loadStatus" oncomplete="callOncomplete()"/>
        </apex:selectList>
        <apex:image id="closeIcon" onclick="resetInfoDOM();" value="/s.gif" alt="Clear" styleclass="closeIcon" rendered="{!productCode != null && FMP != true}"/>
        <a href="#" onclick="openLookupPopup('{!$Component.firstLookup}', '{!$Component.pName}','{!$Component.FName}'); return false">
        <apex:image id="lookupIcon" value="/a.gif" alt="New Window" styleclass="lookupIcon"  onmouseout="this.className = 'lookupIcon';this.className = 'lookupIcon';" onmouseover="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';this.className = 'lookupIconOn';" title="{!$Label.ALabel}"/>
        </a>
        </div>
        </span>
        </apex:actionRegion>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

**Below section is in an OutputPanel. DOM path is `thePage:editForm:editFormBlock:someoutputpanel.`**

```
<apex:outputPanel id="someoutputpanel">
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="pagesectionID2">
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$objecttype.Afield2.label}"/>
        <apex:actionRegion >
        <apex:inputField value="{!objvar.Afield2}" id="textId"/>
        </apex:actionRegion>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="pagesectionID3">
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$objecttype.Afield3.label}"/>
        <apex:actionRegion >
        <apex:inputField value="{!objvar.Afield3}" id="checboxId"/>
        </apex:actionRegion>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

When I click the  , the text field and Check box needs to become null in the UI. However I see that Only text becomes empty and
Checkbox does not. I tried to replicate the same in my Developer edition to see if there is something wrong with Check box. So I created below VF page to
reproduce the error.

```
<apex:page id="thepage" standardController="Opportunity" extensions="OpportunityExt">  
 <apex:form id="theform"> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize(){ 
        document.getElementById("thepage:theform:atextId").value=null;
        document.getElementById("thepage:theform:closedcheckboxId").value=null;
        }
        </script> 

          <apex:outputPanel id="inputId">
          <apex:commandbutton id="saveBtn" onclick="initialize();" value="Search" />
          </apex:outputPanel>
          <apex:outputPanel id="outputId">
             <apex:outputLabel value="{!$objecttype.Opportunity.fields.IsClosed__c.label}"/> 
             <apex:actionRegion >
               <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.IsClosed__c}" id="closedcheckboxId"/> 
             </apex:actionRegion> 
             <apex:outputLabel value="{!$objecttype.Opportunity.fields.OrderNumber__c.label}"/> 
             <apex:actionRegion >
               <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.OrderNumber__c}" id="atextId"/> 
             </apex:actionRegion>                          
          </apex:outputPanel>
          <apex:outputPanel id="outputId2">
             <apex:outputLabel value="{!$objecttype.Opportunity.fields.TrackingNumber__c.label}"/> 
               <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.TrackingNumber__c}" id="trackingId"/>                        
          </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

**This worked!!**. But I noticed something. When I click the button the text disappeared immediately and checkbox was unchecked only after the page
go refreshed. In my VF page, the page does not get refreshed and I thing that could be an issue. I do not have an option to refresh the whole page
again in my problematic VF page(not the above one from DEV org)

What I am trying to understand is how it works differently for a check box and text field. Any insights of what I could be missing is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkboxes have a "value", but that's the value submitted to the server (it default to "on" when checked, and nothing otherwise), but to actually modify its checked state, you need to use `checked`:

```
    document.getElementById("thepage:theform:closedcheckboxId").checked = false;
```

See [`<input type="checkbox" />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) for more details on how checkboxes work.

Comment: Awesome! :) I read that link and got the concept. But wondering how did it work in my developer edition VF page that I have in the question. In that page, the page refreshes once I click the button. So does that mean the checkbox value is send as null when refresh happens?

Comment: @SfdcBat Yes, since "no value" was submitted, the checkbox was parsed as being "off". But this was something the server did, and you shouldn't rely on that behavior.